# React navigation - "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router.getStateForAction')"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm getting this error :

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router.getStateForAction')
```

here is the [code on snack](https://snack.expo.io/@wolfwar/intrigued-pretzels)

and this is a [screenshot from emulator on my comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfk0z.png)

this is a relevant code

```
const App = () => <AppContainer />;

const AppSwitchNavigator = () =>
  createSwitchNavigator({
    WelcomeScreen
  });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export default App;
```

not sure am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a function instead of a Navigator to createAppContainer

Change

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = () =>
  createSwitchNavigator({
    WelcomeScreen
  });
```

to

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({ WelcomeScreen });
```

Comment: thank you... I was actually downgrading packages to solve this /facepalm